# How do the arguments to String#replace's callback get set?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

```
var ourData = '<h1><%= myProperty %></h1>';
var instance = this;
return ourData.replace(/<%=\s+(.*?)\s+%>/g, function (m, m1) {
    return instance.model[m1]; 
    // Here m1 is set to "<%= myProperty %>" and m1 is set to "myProperty"
    // FYI, model[m1] is "Hello World"
});
```

I just cant understand the logic how **m** and **m1** gets the values **"<%= myProperty %>"** and **"myProperty"** respectively.

Could someone please explain to me how this parameters gets the values they get and what is the logic behind it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note: This has nothing to do with closures or with the fact you're defining the function "dynamically." It's purely about how `String#replace` works. I've updated the title and tags a bit. :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you call `String#replace` passing in a function as the second argument, `replace` will call that function for matches it finds. (It'll make one call for the first match if the regex doesn't have the `g` flag, or one call for *each* match if — like yours — it does.)

Each time `replace` calls the callback, the first argument it provides is the *entire* matched string (the entire string that matched your expression). Then it gives the values of any capture groups you've defined in the regex as subsequent arguments after that, in order.

In your case, your regular expression *as a whole* matches `<%= myProperty %>`, and the capture group you have in the expression matches `myProperty`.

Completely subjective, but I tend to use the argument names `m` and then `c0`, `c1`, etc., to remind myself what I'm dealing with. `m` = "match", and of course `c0` is the first capture group, etc.

A slightly simpler example may help: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/jozocale/1)

```
var str = "mumble x123 blah x234 mumfff x345";

console.log("String: '" + str + "'");
str = str.replace(/x(\d+)/g, function(m, c0) {
    console.log("m = '" + m + "', c0 = '" + c0 + "'");
    return "y" + c0;
});
console.log("Result: '" + str + "'");
```

When we run that, we get:

```
String: 'mumble x123 blah x234 mumfff x345'
m = 'x123', c0 = '123'
m = 'x234', c0 = '234'
m = 'x345', c0 = '345'
Result: 'mumble [123] blah [234] mumfff [345]'
```

...because the regular expression *as a whole* matches an `x` followed by one or more digits, and we're using a capture group to get those digits (and then returning a replacement that puts those digits in `[]`, leaving off the `x`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! Its clear now. Great explanation. Thanks again!